# Site-Recommendation for "What is the longest-running endless loop?"

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Which site does this question belong on?

It is my contention that any and every endless loop is going to end rather sooner than later.
Just for curiosity: "What is currently the longest-running known implementation of an endless loop?"

I'm in search for a technical device with an active program running an endless loop. It needs to be a known technical implementation within this universe, not some hypothetical machine / idea or abstract concept.

Comment: https://quora.com ?

Comment: Your question would not be appropriate anywhere on StackExchange - we don't do list-style questions where you have to find the 'longest running x', 'biggest x' or 'most popular x' because answers can range from incorrect, to impossible to prove correct, to outright opinionated

Comment: Thanks alot for the insight. I guess quora.com will be the most appropriate choice.

Comment: You might want to be careful with definitions in a question like that. Would a clock count as a program running an endless loop? Some mechanical clocks have been running for ages, and you could argue that they are mechanical computers.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta I guess no matter how careful I (not being a lawyer) would phrase a definition, someone would find a loophole. Thus I rather convey the spirit of the question. (This advice of course doesn't apply to `Puzzles` or `PCG`.)

Comment: Nevertheless, I felt restricting it to 'electrical' devices would cancel out mechanical computers performing some process. Maybe 'in code' would be sufficient? But what about code turned into hardware (FPGA for a start)?

Comment: Perhaps you should ask the Guinness Book of Records?

Comment: Guys, you can stop the downvotes. :-) The correct answer to this question is 'None'. Do we really want to discourage using `site-recommendation` as a filter before actually posting a question?

Comment: For what it's worth, I'm sure you could find a way to format this in such a way that it would fit on Worldbuliding.

Answer (score 2):

This question does not fit the criteria for any StackExchange site.

As @angussidney says:

> we don't do list-style questions where you have to find the 'longest running x', 'biggest x' or 'most popular x' because answers can range from incorrect, to impossible to prove correct, to outright opinionated

[citation needed]